# Applying a single leaflet search control to search multiple layers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, search

I am attempting to add a single search button to look through geoJSON layers. They will look through the field "name". Unfortunately, my method of creating a layer group is not working. What am I missing? Or how do I group together geoJSON files to make this work?

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
      layer: [syriaLayer, countryBoundary],
      zoom: 7.5,
      propertyName: 'Sheet_Numb',
      circleLocation: false
  });
```

Comment: This works fine for GeoJSON markers only but doesn't work for GeoJSON polygons. How to put multiple GeoJSON markers and polygons in one search box?

Comment: you should ask a new question referencing this discussion - few will see this because you've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the layers within a `layerGroup` or a `featureGroup` as described [in the docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup)

```
layer: L.featureGroup([syriaLayer, countryBoundary]),
```