# Search feature property in a leaflet layerGroup not producing a result

Tags: leaflet, javascript, search

#### Background

I am trying to build a web map (using leaflet) that shows the location and extent of orienteering maps owned by a number of clubs/organisations in my state. Each club/organisation has a layer that is populated with their maps. To make finding these maps easier, the ability to search by name is required.

#### The Problem

To be able to search all layers at once I have grouped them into a layerGroup ([as suggested in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/166212/109705)). This does not produce a result when I attempt to search for a map (the developer console throws the error `TypeError: a.getLatLng is not a function` in relation to leaflet-search.js). Searching with only one layer **does** produce a satisfactory result (and doesn't throw an error).

[Here is my current code](https://github.com/Damned-truths/Damned-truths.github.io/blob/master/Database/index.html)
[The webmap with search through multiple layers](http://damned-truths.github.io/Database/)
[The webmap with search through only one layer](http://damned-truths.github.io/Database/index2.html)

How can this error be solved? Is there a better method to search through multiple layers?

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by using the JQuery autocomplete control. My example uses three different polygon layers, In the onEachFeature I tagged the layer_id with  the feature attribute I was going to search on. I also pushed the attribute and the layer name into an array for each layer. Then I combined all three arrays, sorted it, removed duplicates, and then used it as the autocompletes source. I ran into a timing issue as the control loaded before it's source data but was able to get around that. The next step was when they chose a name, I made sure the layer was on, and did a fire event to highlight, popup, and zoom to.

Here is a working example. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/senate/index.html